# Implementing Server-Side Paging with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS app. I am loading a LOT of data from the server and displaying it in a data table. I am using [angular-datatables](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/serverSideProcessing) for my data table. Currently, my HTML looks like this:

```
<table datatable="orders" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-column-defs="orderColumns">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Customer</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="order in orders">
      <td>{{order.ID}}</td>
      <td>{{order.OrderDate}}</td>
      <td>{{order.Customer}}</td>
      <td>{{order.Amount}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The properties I'm binding to are in my controller. That looks like this:

```
$scope.currentPageNumber = 1;
$scope.dtOptions = {displayLength: 25, deferRender: true};
$scope.orders = [];

$scope.loadOrders = function() {
  // hit the server here and get orders for the selected page
  // getOrders($scope.currentPageNumber);
};
```

After reading the docs, I'm still stuck on how to implement server-side paging. Specifically, I'm not sure how to handle the pager in the control.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's up to your particular backend how it handles pagination.

For Python, I use [Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/api.html), and it makes pagination in my Flask and SQLAlchemy apps a breeze. You pass in the current page number and (optionally) how many items per page you'd like -- I send them as query parameters in the XHR -- and it returns from the database only those items that fall within that offset and length.

Most other backend frameworks have a very similar pagination operation, e.g. the [same thing in PHP with Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/pagination)

On the front end, I've been leveraging the Angular [ui-boostrap pagination control](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination).